# What is the proper way to fill in URL params http://myhost/path/{param1}/{param2} in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have REST api with URLs like

```
http://myhost/path/{param1}/{param2}
```

I know I can urlencode and compose it myself, may be some function like `requests.get` alsready does this?

Comment: Just regular Python string formatting? `requests.get(f'http://myhost/path/{param1}/{param2}')` would insert the values of variables named `param1` and `param2` in the appropriate places.

Comment: Without url encoding

Answer (score -1):

```
param1 = 'spaghetti'
param2 = 'meatballs'

print(f'http://myhost/path/{param1}/{param2}')
# http://myhost/path/spaghetti/meatballs
```

Comment: This doesn't do URL ecoding, for example, imagine params contain spaces. They should be replaced with `%20` or `+`

Comment: [Try this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?